# WordPress Search goes to post page when you do a blank search

Tags: wordpress, search

Yea so on my wordpress theme I've put together...

When you click the search button (with the search field empty) it takes you to the blog page. I have assigned the index.php as the blog page and made another page and assigned that as the home page.

Can anyone help? Its not a major problem but it is a little glitch I would like to get rid of.

Thanks.

Terry

Comment: It will be better if you send your search.php

Comment: ok here http://tny.cz/942a7c36 hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

I also faced the same problem, it is default given by wordpress.

but luckily I found something which helped me.

Add below in "Functions.php"

```
 function SearchFilter($query) {
    // If 's' request variable is set but empty
    if (isset($_GET['s']) && empty($_GET['s']) && $query->is_main_query()){
        $query->is_search = true;
        $query->is_home = false;
    }
    return $query;}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

and then replace below line(line no 15) in search.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() && strlen( trim(get_search_query()) ) != 0 ) : ?>
```

Might be it will help you too

For details read this : [Customize empty search wordpress](http://www.evagoras.com/2012/11/01/how-to-handle-and-customize-an-empty-search-query-in-wordpress/#comment-12185)